# Make Safari Browser appear in iPad/iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an app that I am in the process of writing and I want too have a button on the screen that the user can press to go to a web page in safari.  I do not want to use the UIWebView control and make my own browser, I just want the screen to switch to Safari.

Can any give me some tips how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do it with this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]];
```